# Vue + Vuetify data table first column image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-data-tables

I am using **Vue + Vuetify** and I am trying to add image in the first column.

> Table Template Code

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :search="search"
  light
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
    <td><img :src="props.item.name" style="width: 50px; height: 50px"></td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
  </template>
  <v-alert slot="no-results" :value="true" dir="rtl" color="error" icon="warning">
    {{ PRODUCTS_TABLE_TEXT.NO_RESULT }} "{{ search }}"
  </v-alert>
</v-data-table>
```

> Table Script Code

```
data () {
  return {
    //TEXT
    PRODUCTS_TABLE_TEXT: products_table_text,
    //TABLE DATA
    search: '',
    headers: [
      {
        text: products_table_text.columns.IMAGE,
        align: 'center',
        sortable: false,
        value: 'image'
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
    ],
    desserts: [
      {
        value: false,
        name: '1.jpg',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

> What I have tried to do

I have tried to add the **HTML image code** in the **name** variable like  this:

```
name: '<img src="./../../assets/products-images/1.jpg" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">'
```

But it just printed the HTML as a text and did not render it.

Comment: it should be `name:"./../../assets/products-images/1.jpg"`

Comment: Yea you are right I have tried that too but it did not load the image even if the path is correct i don't know why!

Comment: Can you add your json data as well to the question

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: from where are you getting item.carbs data that you are populating on html?

Comment: The data are static and defined in the script in the code that I have posted

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJxBpQ?&editors=101 Is this what you want? I guess you just need to fix your path.

Answer (score 9):

I am also stacked for som minute but this is the easy way to use an image in vuetify data table
Table Template Code

```
  <template>
 <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs12>
        <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="carts" class="elevation-0">
          <template v-slot:item.image="{ item }">
            <div class="p-2">
              <v-img :src="item.image" :alt="item.name" height="100px"></v-img>
            </div>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
<template/>
```

Table Script Code

```
  <script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
    data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      isAvalibel: false,
      headers: [
        { text: "Image", value: "image", sortable: false },
        { text: "Product Name", value: "name", sortable: false },
      ]
    };
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["carts"])
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

During template compilation, the compiler can transform certain attributes, such as src URLs, into require calls, so that the target asset can be handled by webpack. For example, `<img src="./foo.png">` will attempt to locate the file `./foo.png` on your file system and include it as a dependency of your bundle.

so, for dynamic attribute src,

`<td>
    <img :src="require('./assets/products-images/' +props.item.name)">
</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many ways you can use to insert image inside your Vue app/template:

1) (This is what you need for your code) Using `require` function actually this is going to be handled by the webpack and map the image to it's resource.

```
<img :src="require('./assets/products-images/' + props.item.name)">
```

please follow the below github discussion for more explanation:

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/126

2) Another way read the image as `base64` from the server and handle that inside your Vue app:

```
<img v-bind:src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+imageBytes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your server images with axios and display them in the rows, this works too.

```
<template v-slot:item.image="{ item }">
    <img v-bind:src="`/${item.image}`" style="width: 50px; height:50px">
    </v-img>
</template>
```